# How to control navigation history in webview inside fragment

Tags: android, webview, fragment, state

I have a webview inside fragment and I want it to be controlled by the navigation history whenever I press the back button.

In my case, when I press the back button I leave the webview, but I want that on pressing the button I will return to the state that is stored in the navigation history (from before leaving the webview).

Any solution please?

I tried with `onKey` but it does not resolve my problem. Here my code:

```
public class FragmentAll extends Fragment implements
        DialogInterface.OnCancelListener, DialogInterface.OnDismissListener,
        OnDownloaExpodTerminated {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        FragmentAll f = new FragmentAll();
        return f;
    }

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        (((MainActivity) getActivity()) ).setActionBarTitle("Store");
        myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        setWebview();
        v.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    myWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a method inside your Fragment class:

```
public void goBackWebview(){
    myWebview.goBack();
}
```

Now, go to the Activity class to which this fragment is attached and override the onBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //if webview has history
    myFragment.goBackWebView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to manage list of links is loaded in your webview.
you can get the url like this

```
    web_des2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    HitTestResult hitTestResult = web_des2.getHitTestResult();

                    if (hitTestResult != null) {
                        String url = hitTestResult.getExtra();

                        if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
                                             yourUrlList.add(url);
                                             web_des2.loadUrl(url);
                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

you can check onBackPress if your list does not empty then get url form list and load it into webview and remove from the list.
you can use Stack to store url so become easy you can use pop() and push() function directly. if like than +1